# Ubuntu Server 18.04 with Postfix

Tags: postfix

Good Day,

I have POSTFIX + Courier-IMAP + Courier-POP on UbuntuServer 18.04; The server has two network cards; 1 card connected to the Internet with Dynamic IP and the other card to the local network.

I have public domain with a provider on the Internet, but the server is physically in the company.

The mail server works well in the private network, I can send and receive emails, to and from the Internet.

The problem is that from my house or any place outside the private network, and using my mail server, I can not send mail to any recipient, I have the error of RELAY ACCESS DENIED. What is failing in the configuration on my server?

```
**********************************
FILE >> **main.cf:**

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu) 
biff = no 
append_dot_mydomain = no 
readme_directory = no 
compatibility_level = 2 
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem 
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes 
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache                      
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_auth_destination permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated permit_inet_interfaces defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = ubuntusrv  
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases  
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myorigin, ubuntusrv, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 192.10.0.0/24 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0   
recipient_delimiter = + 
inet_interfaces = 
all inet_protocols = ipv4
home_mailbox = Maildir/ 
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir 
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/enviados.list

******************
FILE >>  master.cf
```

Comment: This question is not unclear, and it's not too broad. It's about one specific topic, and if clarification is required, use a comment to ask!

Answer (score 0):

This is because postfix by default does not relay mail for other hosts. It accepts e-mail for the domains it is configured to receive mail for (`mydestination`), and relays mail for `mynetworks`.

This is so that a spammer can not use your e-mail server to send spam. Running an open relay is a **very** bad idea, as it will probably be abused in minutes, and may possibly violate your ISPs Terms of Service, leading to termination of internet service.

This behavior is controlled by the following section (split up by me to improve readability):

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_auth_destination, 
                           permit_mynetworks,
                           permit_sasl_authenticated,
                           permit_inet_interfaces,
                           defer_unauth_destination
```

As we can see, you allow authorized destinations, your own networks, sasl-authenticated clients and inet_interfaces (e.g. IP-address of the client matches one of the IP's of the machine running the mailserver, effectively allowing local access). When you're outside your own network and try to send mail to a third party, you're effectively in the unauth_destination-group - which is not permitted.

The solution is to authenticate the user to the mailserver. Configure postfix with a TLS certificate (even a self signed will do, or use Let's Encrypt), and use StartTLS to encrypt communication so you can safely transmit a password.

To configure Postfix to use encryption, add the following above your current configuration:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/path/to/certificate.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/path/to/key.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_tls_security_level = may
```

Then configure whichever mailclient you are using to use StartTLS, and authenticate using an account on the mailserver.

**DO NOT BE TEMPTED TO CONFIGURE YOUR MAIL SERVER AS AN OPEN RELAY!** Running an open relay will get you blacklisted **everywhere** in a very short time. Configure authentication!